# How to export laravel blade to word document

Tags: laravel, ms-word, export, laravel-blade

I want to add export to word functionality to one of my **blades** in Laravel. I have used this package.

```
composer require phpoffice/phpword
```

My Controller including export to word functionality is below. When user inserts obj_id in a blade form the controller gets the first and last name from hrp1702 table. The export to word takes place inside controller. I want to add this functionality to a blade however. Is that possible?

This is the controller

```
public function work(Request $bb)
    {


        $cc = $bb -> get('obj_id');


        $m = DB::table('hrp1702') -> where('object_id', $cc)->value('first_name');
        $n = DB::table('hrp1702') -> where('object_id', $cc)->value('last_name');



        $wordTest = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
        $newSection = $wordTest->addSection();

        $newSection->addText('FIRST NAME: '.$m);
        $newSection->addText('LAST NAME: '.$n);

        $objectWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($wordTest, 'Word2007');
        try 
        {
            $objectWriter->save(storage_path('TestWordFile.docx'));
        } 
        catch (Exception $e) 
        {
        }

        return response()->download(storage_path('TestWordFile.docx'));


    }

}
```

Below you can see the blade I want to export to word. It is a very simple blade which takes fist and last name from a db table. I want to add to the button at the bottom that export to word on click. Not inside controller. Could you assist please?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="el">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Full Name</title>
</head>
<body>

First Name: <b> {{ $onoma }}</b><br>
Last Name: <b> {{ $epitheto }}</b><br>

<form method="post" action='/exagogi1'>


    <input type="submit" value="Export to Word" />
</form>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi @Konstantinos. Your question is currently pretty vague, so it's difficult to assist you. Can you show us what you tried? Are you receiving an error? SO is not a good place for "How do I do this?" questions.

Comment: Hi Aken. In fact I want to add export to word to this blade. In fact what I want to do is this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iqCOgIzoNpQ&t=198s but it does not work in frameworks (I have added relevant code to controller but does not work.